# How to fix 'fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "..." does not exist'

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to use a Bash script to download NOAA GOES data. It works on a colleagues computer but does not work on mine. I get the 'fatal error' even though the files do exists in the S3 bucket, which is a public bucket that anyone can download from. I can download a file without issue when I enter the aws s3 command at prompt, but cannot get them do download using a text file and the code that iterates through the file entries. Does anyone have an idea what else could be causing the HeadObject error?

I've checked for spelling mistakes and manipulating forward slashes, but nothing appears to be wrong. I can download a file manually at the command prompt, but not when iterating through a variable for the files.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Purpose: Pulls GOES16 Full Disk data from Amazon Web Services S3 bucket
#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!#!   


           ##############################################################################
# Clean files from previous script run

rm DesiredData.txt
rm FullList.txt
```

#

```
echo "Please be patient. Script is reading available GOES-16 files for today from AWS bucket."
```

#

## Get current date

```
DAYS=`date +%j`
YEARS=`date +%Y`
```

## CHANNELS

```
CHANNELS='C01 C02 C03'
```

## ABI PRODUCTS

```
PRODUCTS='L1b-RadF'
```

#

## Get list of remote files available for current date and send list to text file

```
for PRODUCT in $PRODUCTS; do
for YEAR in $YEARS; do
for DAY in $DAYS; do
aws s3 ls --recursive noaa-goes16/ABI-$PRODUCT/$YEAR/$DAY/ | awk '{print $3";"$4}' >> FullList.txt
done
done
done
```

## Make new list for channel 1-3 data from the output text file above

```
for CHANNEL in $CHANNELS; do
grep "$CHANNEL"_G16_s"$YEAR$DAY"[0-9][0-9][0][0] FullList.txt >>     DesiredData.txt
done
```

#

## Download files from list of DesiredData.txt

```
for x in $(cat DesiredData.txt);
do
SIZE=$(echo $x | cut -d";" -f1)
FULLNAME=$(echo $x | cut -d";" -f2)
NAME=$(echo $x | cut -d"/" -f5)
echo "Processing file $FULLNAME"

if [ -f $NAME ]; then
    echo "This file exists locally"
    LOCALSIZE=$(du -sb $NAME | awk '{ print $1 }')
    if [ $LOCALSIZE -ne $SIZE ]; then
        echo "The size of the file is not the same as the remote file. Downloading again..."
    aws s3 cp s3://noaa-goes16/"$FULLNAME" ./
    else
    echo "The size of the file matches the remote file. Not downloading it again."
    fi
    else
    echo "This file does not exist locally, downloading..."
    aws s3 cp s3://noaa-goes16/"$FULLNAME" ./
fi

done
```

When I run this code, I get the following when it reached the download section: 'fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "ABI-L1b-RadF/2019/147/00/OR_ABI-L1b-RadF-M6C01_G16_..." does not exist'

Comment: aws s3 cp s3://noaa-goes16/"$FULLNAME" ./ --> this command downloads the object from S3 to local, the error clearly says the object doesn't exist, you need to make sure that you have the prefix/key/path correct in variable $FULLNAME.

Comment: Thanks, James! I checked the path from the list created and was able to download it directly from the command prompt but originally not using the script. However, I was able to solve the issue and the script now works. The problem was that the text was being created in Windows, which I now realize, adds a line break character to the end of each line, which was called along with the path and creating the error. To clean the file of those breaks, I installed "dos2unix" and incorporated "dos2unix DesiredData.txt" to the script before the downloading process.